# Not able to retrieve string from Array

Tags: c++, c

I am writing a program to store the name of item and price using array.
But here not able to retrieve the item name from the array. The program crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main()
{
    char itemName[100];
    int n=0, i,j, total=0, itemPrice[1];

    printf("Enter number of items: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    //fflush(stdin);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Item name: \n");
        scanf("%s", &itemName[i]);
            for (j = i ; j<=i; j++ )

            {
                printf("Enter the price\n");

                scanf("%d", &itemPrice[j]);

                total += itemPrice[j];
            }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)

        printf(" %s", itemName[i]);

        for (j = i ; j<=i; j++)

            printf("\t\t%s\n", itemPrice[j]);

}
```

Comment: Please choose either *one of* C or C++. Why don't you use standard `int main(void)` instead of implementation-defined `void main()`, which is illegal in C++?

Comment: Are you trying to push more than 1 item price into `itemPrice[1]` ?

Comment: Why do you use the inner loop? Try to replace it with `scanf("%d", &itemPrice[i]);`

Comment: If this is C, you invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()` : `%s` calls for `char*`, but you passed `itemPrice[j]`, which is `int`.

Comment: @Marievi Why not just use `scanf("%d", &itemPrice[i]);`?

Comment: @MikeCAT yes, right!

Comment: @Ash You need at least to declare a two-dimensional array of type char for storing names.

Comment: `itemName` is an array of 100 `char`s, not 100 strings. `itemName[i]` is a `char`; printf-ing it with `%s` is undefined. You only have one price in `itemPrice`. `for(j = i ; j<=i;j++)` is a *very* roundabout way of doing something exactly once.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Declaraing an array of pointer to `char` is an alternative way without declaraing two-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate enough space to store strings and integers.
Also, you have to use correct format specifier for `printf()`, or you may invoke *undefined behavior*.

The loop `for (j = i ; j<=i; j++)` is not harmful, but almost meaningless and confusing.

Also note that you are iterating only to print the name annd not to print the price in the latter half of the program.

Possible fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ITEM_MAX 100

int main(void)
{
    char itemName[ITEM_MAX][1000];
    int n=0, i, total=0, itemPrice[ITEM_MAX];

    printf("Enter number of items: \n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
    {
        fputs("read error\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Item name: \n");
        /* Specify the length to read in order to avoid buffer overrun. */
        /* Don't forget to reserve space for terminating null-character. */
        if (scanf("%999s", itemName[i]) != 1)
        {
            fputs("read error\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Enter the price\n");

        if (scanf("%d", &itemPrice[i]) != 1)
        {
            fputs("read error\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        total += itemPrice[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        printf(" %s", itemName[i]);

        printf("\t\t%d\n", itemPrice[i]);
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main()
{
   char itemName[100][100];
   int n=0, i,j, total=0, itemPrice[100];

   printf("Enter number of items: \n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
        printf("Item name: \n");
        scanf("%s", &itemName[i]);
         printf("Enter the price\n");
        scanf("%d", &itemPrice[i]);
         total += itemPrice[i];

  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  printf(" %s", itemName[i]);
  for (j = 0 ; j<n; j++)
  printf("\t\t%s\n", itemPrice[j]);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
itemPrice[1];
```

that above statement tells,your going to store only one data that too in itemprice[0]....if you save something in itemprice[2] (or greater than 0 is error)

i can see many error, better go step by step